# ZF2 Form Collections Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am having a very strange problem.  When using my development environment (Windows host shared on Ubuntu Guest) the follow code works fine. However when on a linux server or even if I copy the files to the Ubuntu Guest but a native direction (Not shared from the host) the code fails.  The error that I am receiving is:

```
Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for RA\Restriction\Form\ValueFieldset
```

So the problem is that it's never able to locates the file.  The stack trace dies at

```
/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('RA...', true)
```

Here is what my form file looks like

```
namespace RA\Restriction\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class RestrictionValueForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
    // we want to ignore the name passed
    parent::__construct('attribute');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
        ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());;
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'restriction_id',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'hidden',
            'id' => 'restriction_id',
        ),
    ));
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'collection',
        'name' => 'value_name',
        'options' => array(
            'count' => 2,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
            'label' => '',
            'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'RA\Restriction\Form\ValueFieldset',
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary mar-right5',
            'value' => 'Save',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'cancel',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'button',
            'class' => 'btn',
            'value' => 'Cancel',
            'id' => 'cancel',
        ),
    ));
    }
}
```

I've been working on this all day and haven't been able to come up with a solution I even built a couple extra environments and make sure the configs were identical.  Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: In path /module/RA/src/RA/Restriction/Form/ValueFieldset.php

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problem.  It appears that in some environments it did not like the fieldset being in a sub directory.  I was able to move my fieldsset to /RA/src/RA/Form/ValueFieldset and everything is happy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem. It appears that in some environments it did not like the fieldset being in a sub directory. I was able to move my fieldsset to /RA/src/RA/Form/ValueFieldset and everything is happy now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in my case, was case sensitivity. Windows is not case sensitive in directory structures and in general but linux is case sensitive.

Comment: That's my problem too.